# Why latex file shows some characters instead of digits?

Tags: symbols, overleaf, text, winedt, italic-correction

I wrote a text in overleaf and then i transferred the file to winedit. But, some digits and characters are shown wrongly with some symbols.

Formula in overleaf vs formula transferred in winedit

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! PLease show us a code for equation (as part of complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe you transfer the formula to winedit, but not the preamble of the document?